# How to create a Regular Expression for a span attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, asp.net-mvc

Ok, I admit it, I suck at Regular Expressions. I'm trying to get the value of attribute data-hover-id.

I have the following javascript code:

```
var editText = "<span class='hover-content' data-hover-id='2' >Some text</span>";

var hoverId = -1;

// Get HoverID if it exists
var regex = /span.*data-hover-id=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/;
var result = regex.exec(editText);
if (result.length > 1) {
  hoverId = result[1];
}
```

The results of the above code is hoverId equals '2 (apostrophe 2).

I want the value 2 without the quote or apostrophe. What would the regular expression be in this case? Is there a better way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Why not simply use [`elem.getAttribute('data-hover-id');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute), or do you *have* to do this with string manipulation?

Comment: This string is be manipulated.

Comment: The question wasn't if you need to manipulate the string afterwards, but if you have to use string manipulation to find the value you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your regex much simpler like:

```
var re = /data-hover-id=["'](.+)["']/;
var result = re.exec(str)[1];
```

**Edit:** If you need to account for no quotes at all try this one:

```
/data-hover-id=['"]?([^\s>]+)['"]?/
```

Comment: This works, but note that it is *very* specific to the current string.

Comment: This doesn't account for the possibility of `'`, `"` or nothing surrounding the `2`.

Comment: Attribute quotation is [optional (apparently), so long as the attribute itself doesn't contain white-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted).

Comment: `data-hover-id=2` is legal HTML, or is at least recognised by most browsers.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Posted an edit. And yes it is legal in HTML (not XHTML) but I guess it depends on where is that HTML coming from. I personally never use unquoted attributes.

Comment: Me neither, but, y'know, *some do...* (in strange, backwards places, where tags are *still* written in uppercase, and the `<CENTER>` is still found...)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way (avoiding the messy string-manipulation):

```
var editText = "<span class='hover-content' data-hover-id='2' >Some text</span>",
    tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = editText;
tmp.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tmp);
var hoverId = tmp.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].getAttribute('data-hover-id');
tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);

alert(hoverId);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXGrP/).

However, given that:

> This string is be manipulated.

I'll also offer:

```
var editText = "<span class='hover-content' data-hover-id='2' >Some text</span>",
    parts = editText.split(/\s+/),
    hoverId = -1;

for (var i = 0, len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (parts[i].indexOf('data-hover-id') == 0) {
        hoverId = parseInt(parts[i].split('=')[1].match(/\d+/), 10)
    }
}
console.log(hoverId);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXGrP/1/).

And a more concise (though perhaps fragile) solution:

```
var editText = '<span class="hover-content" data-hover-id=2 >Some text</span>',
    hoverId = editText.match(/\s?data\-hover\-id=(?:['"])?(\d+)(?:['"])?/)[1] || -1;

console.log(hoverId);
```

Works with single-quoted (`'`) attribute-values: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXGrP/8/).

Works with double-quoted (`"`) attribute-values: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXGrP/7/).

Work with unquoted values: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rXGrP/6/).