# Creating a regex to parse html to MXML syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched a lot over stackoverflow and found very interesting that's includes:

[How to create a Regular Expression for a span attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829448/how-to-create-a-regular-expression-for-a-span-attribute)

And 
[Javascript regex to replace text div and &lt; &gt;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153349/javascript-regex-to-replace-text-div-and-lt-gt)

But turns out that I couldn't really manage to parse my goal to replace div with the data-type attribute and remove the data-type attribute over the strings.

Here's how I did.

```
//Doesn't work with multi lines, just get first occurrency and nothing more.
// Regex: /\s?data\-type\=(?:['"])?(\d+)(?:['"])?/

var source_code = $("body").html();

var rdiv = /div/gm; // remove divs
var mxml = source_code.match(/\S?data\-type\=(?:['"])?(\w+)(?:['"])?/);
var rattr =source_code.match(/\S?data\-type\=(?:['"])?(\w+)(?:['"])/gm);
var outra = source_code.replace(rdiv,'s:'+mxml[1]);
var nestr = outra.replace(rattr[0],'');// worked with only first element
console.log(nestr);
console.log(mxml);
console.log(rattr);
```

Over this HTML sample page

```
<div id="app" data-type="Application">
    <div data-type="Label"></div>
     <div data-type="Button"></div>
     <div data-type="VBox"></div>
     <div data-type="Group"></div>
</div>
```

Any light on that specific thing? I may missing something, but I really have no clue, there's no left space otherwise asking here.

I've created a jsFiddle to show, just open the console of browser to see the results I have with me.

http://jsfiddle.net/uWCjV/

Feel free to answer over jsfiddle or a better explanation of my regex, why it's fails.

Until I get any feedback, I will keep trying to see if I can manage to replace the text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused as to what your goal is

Comment: [never use regex for html parsing/manipulation.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) <=

Comment: My goal is to change from html to mxml tags syntax. I'm just lost over escape data-type="" over the inner value.

Comment: var x=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0; i<x.length;i++) {
alert(x[i].getAttribute('data-type'));
}

Comment: Probably I missed your goal. - This was just for the aspect of RegEx.

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT? (assuming the HTML markup is well formed)

Comment: Hi there Jani, yep I considered that option, but I'm really interesting on using Regex to be simpler as possible.

Comment: @ultima_rat0 I can get the data-type values, using kind of way, but I'm intend to use only regex.

I could find a way of doing that like:

`/\s?data\-type=(?:['"])?(\w+)(?:['"])/gm`

But it just takes the first element and doesn't consider /gm option in the end.

I've changed to \S to not conside white space. But lead me to no where.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to parse the markup into a tree of Objects and then convert that into MXML.

Something like this:

```
var source_code = $("body").html();

var openStartTagRx = /^\s*<div/i;
var closeStartTagRx = /^\s*>/i;
var closeTagRx = /^\s*<\/div>/i;
var attrsRx = new RegExp(
    '^\\s+' +
    '(?:(data-type)|([a-z-]+))' +    // group 1 is "data-type" group 2 is any attribute
    '\\=' +
    '(?:\'|")' +
    '(.*?)' +                        // group 3 is the data-type or attribute value
    '(?:\'|")',
    'mi');


function Thing() {
    this.type = undefined;
    this.attrs = undefined;
    this.children = undefined;
}

Thing.prototype.addAttr = function(key, value) {
    this.attrs = this.attrs || {};
    this.attrs[key] = value;
};

Thing.prototype.addChild = function(child) {
    this.children = this.children || [];
    this.children.push(child);
};


function getErrMsg(expected, str) {
    return 'Malformed source, expected: ' + expected + '\n"' + str.slice(0,20) + '"';
}


function parseElm(str) {

    var result,
        elm,
        childResult;

    if (!openStartTagRx.test(str)) {
        return;
    }
    elm = new Thing();
    str = str.replace(openStartTagRx, '');

    // parse attributes
    result = attrsRx.exec(str);
    while (result) {
        if (result[1]) {
            elm.type = result[3];
        } else {
            elm.addAttr(result[2], result[3]);
        }
        str = str.replace(attrsRx, '');
        result = attrsRx.exec(str);
    }

    // close off that tag
    if (!closeStartTagRx.test(str)) {
        throw new Error(getErrMsg('end of opening tag', str));
    }
    str = str.replace(closeStartTagRx, '');

    // if it has child tags
    childResult = parseElm(str);
    while (childResult) {
        str = childResult.str;
        elm.addChild(childResult.elm);
        childResult = parseElm(str);
    }

    // the tag should have a closing tag
    if (!closeTagRx.test(str)) {
        throw new Error(getErrMsg('closing tag for the element', str));
    }
    str = str.replace(closeTagRx, '');
    return {
        str: str,
        elm: elm
    };
}


console.log(parseElm(source_code).elm);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWCjV/1/)

This parses the markup you provided into the following:

```
{ 
  "type" : "Application"
  "attrs" : { "id" : "app" },
  "children" : [
    { "type" : "Label" },
    { "type" : "Button" },
    { "type" : "VBox" },
    { "type" : "Group" }
  ],
}
```

It's recursive, so embedded groups are parsed, too.